# Error passing MPV arguments using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm just trying to open a streaming site using subprocess.Popen and MPV player. The code below works fine.

```py
import subprocess

mpv = subprocess.Popen(["mpv", "http://stream-tx4.radioparadise.com:80/aac-128"])

returncode = mpv.wait()
```

Now, in the second example if I try to pass the url using a variable it doesn't work, I get a 'file station not found' error.

```py
import subprocess

station = "http://stream-tx4.radioparadise.com:80/aac-128"

mpv = subprocess.Popen(["mpv", "station"])

returncode = mpv.wait()
```

My question is why the second example doesn't work? What is the proper method to pass the station url.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have to replace with `station` variable and not using string `"station"`:

```
import subprocess

station = "http://stream-tx4.radioparadise.com:80/aac-128"

mpv = subprocess.Popen(["mpv", station])

returncode = mpv.wait()
```